# How do I change the delimiter for \citeauthor with multiple references and add "and" between the last two?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

```
\citeauthor{iso9241-5,ansi2007,osha3092}
```

produces

> International Organization for Standardization;
>   Human Factors and Ergonomics Society;
>   Occupational Safety and Health Administration

Is there a pretty command to make it produce

> International Organization for Standardization,
>   Human Factors and Ergonomics Society and
>   Occupational Safety and Health Administration

so I don't have to write

```
\citeauthor{iso9241-5}, \citeauthor{ansi2007} and \citeauthor{osha3092}
```

Comment: One could guess natbib is the package, as it is in the list of tags. The style is not yet revealed though. I was interested in the same matter though. I used the plainnat style.

Comment: The command `\citeauthor` is the give-away that the citation management package is `natbib`. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To format the punctuation of `natbib` the package provides the command `\setcitestyle` The character between citations can be set in the following way:

```
\setcitestyle{comma}
```

which is equal to

```
\setcitestyle{citesep={,}}
```

Here an example that can do what you want:
(A bug is possible)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={John Smith},
title={TITLE},
year={2011},
publisher={...},
}
@book{test1,
author={Theodor Fontane},
title={Zaubefloete},
year={1000},
publisher={...},
}
@book{test2,
author={Wolfgang Goethe},
title={Irgendwas},
year={1000},
publisher={...},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\newcount\nat@length@list
\newcount\nat@tempcount
\renewcommand\NAT@sort@cites[1]{%
  \let\NAT@cite@list\@empty
  \nat@length@list=0%
  \@for\@citeb:=#1\do{%
     \global\advance\nat@length@list\@ne%
     \expandafter\NAT@star@cite\@citeb\@@}%
  \if@filesw
    \expandafter\immediate\expandafter\write\expandafter\@auxout
      \expandafter{\expandafter\string\expandafter\citation\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list}}%
  \fi
  \@ifnum{\NAT@sort>\z@}{%
    \expandafter\NAT@sort@cites@\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list}%
  }{}%
}%
%
\def\NAT@def@citea@close{%
 \def\@citea{%
     \NAT@@close%
     \ifnum\nat@length@list=2
         \NAT@space and\NAT@space%
      \else
         \NAT@separator\NAT@space%
      \fi
      \advance\nat@length@list-\@ne%
   }%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\citeauthor{test,test1,test2}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution; instead of modifying the `\citeauthor` command, I defined a new `\CiteList` command to do what you want: it takes a comma separated list of bibliographical keys and calls `\citeauthor` for each element, using `\MidSep` (initially defined as a comma followed by a space) as separator except for the last two elements which will be separated using `\LastSep` (initially defined as the word "and" surrounded by spaces). Redefining `\LastSep` and `\MidSep` you can easily customize the style:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@book{goossens93,
 author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
 title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
 year = "1993",
 publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
 address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@book{knuth84,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {TeX}book",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
}

@unpublished{patashnik88,
   author = "Oren Patashnik",
   title = "Using {BibTeX}",
   note = "Documentation for general BibTeX users",
   month = jan,
   year = 1988
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\MidSep{, }% separator for two elements, not the last two
\newcommand\LastSep{ and }% separator for last two elements
\newcommand\CiteList[1]{%
  \let\last@elem\relax
  \let\last@sep\relax
  \@for\@list:=#1\do{%
    \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
      \ifx\last@sep\relax
        \def\last@sep{\LastSep}% the separator between the last two elements should is "and"
      \else\MidSep  % the separator between two elements (not the two last) is a comma
      \fi
      \citeauthor{\last@elem}%
    \fi
    \let\last@elem\@list
  }% the last element of the list:
  \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
    \last@sep\citeauthor{\last@elem}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\CiteList{goossens93,knuth84,patashnik88}

\renewcommand\LastSep{/}
\renewcommand\MidSep{/}
\CiteList{goossens93,knuth84,patashnik88}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybiblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `natbib`, to force the separator between citations (created, say, via `\citeauthor`) to be a comma instead of a semicolon, you'd type the following in the preamble (after loading the natbib package):

```
\setcitestyle{citesep={,}}
```

However, this change won't insert a nice "and" between the penultimate and final items of the list, which is what you want, right? I guess you'll have to type `\citeauthor{iso9241-5, ansi2007} and \citeauthor{osha3092}`. Not a huge improvement over your initial idea, but at least a small step in the right direction...

Comment: See the second paragraph, which I added after realizing that I'd hit the "Post Your Answer" button prematurely. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an hack inspired by the more elegant approaches of Marco and Mico that provides a \citeauthors command without using TeX primitives.

```
\setcitestyle{comma}
\newcommand\citeauthors[2]{\citeauthor#1 and \citeauthor#2}
\citeauthors{john,paul,george}{ringo}
```

But Marco still wins.