# Separation of last author with \citep

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I came across a solution on how to make an author list where the last author is preceded by "and", as shown in this code:

```
\newcommand\MidSep{, }% separator for two elements, not the last two (for citeauthorlist and citetlist)
\newcommand\LastSep{ and }% separator for last two elements

\newcommand\citetlist[1]{%
  \let\last@elem\relax
  \let\last@sep\relax
  \@for\@list:=#1\do{%
    \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
      \ifx\last@sep\relax
        \def\last@sep{\LastSep}% the separator between the last two elements should is "and"
      \else\MidSep  % the separator between two elements (not the two last) is a comma
      \fi
      \citet{\last@elem}%
    \fi
    \let\last@elem\@list
  }% the last element of the list:
  \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
    \last@sep\citet{\last@elem}%
  \fi
}
```

The output is: Author A (2011); Author B (2012) and Author C (2013)

I want the same, but for `\citep`.  I would like to have: (Author A, 2011; Author B, 2012 and Author C, 2013).

I'm using `natbib` package along with the `IEEEtranSN` bibliography style

Comment: Isn't adding the parentheses and changing the separator to a semicolon sufficient?

Comment: I think this is similar or equal: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27901/how-do-i-change-the-delimiter-for-citeauthor-with-multiple-references-and-add

Comment: @egreg well, I don't want to get parenthesis inside parenthesis (because of the years)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel close, but I want to get inside the parenthesis the author and year as well, without having parenthesis inside parenthesis, thus (Author A, 2011; Author B, 2012 and Author C, 2013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following modification of your code:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MidSep{; }% separator for two elements, not the last two (for citeauthorlist and citetlist)
\newcommand\LastSep{ and }% separator for last two elements
\newcommand\citetlist[1]{%
 \begingroup%
  \let\NAT@open@orig\NAT@open\let\NAT@open\relax\NAT@open@orig
  \let\NAT@close@orig\NAT@close\let\NAT@close\relax%
  \def\NAT@spacechar{, }%
  \let\last@elem\relax
  \let\last@sep\relax
  \@for\@list:=#1\do{%
    \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
      \ifx\last@sep\relax
        \def\last@sep{\LastSep}% the separator between the last two elements should is "and"
      \else\MidSep  % the separator between two elements (not the two last) is a comma
      \fi
      \citet{\last@elem}%
    \fi
    \let\last@elem\@list
  }% the last element of the list:
  \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
    \last@sep\citet{\last@elem}%
  \fi%
 \NAT@close@orig\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

My test file produces the following output:

> [image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300},varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={John Smith},
title={TITLE},
year={2011},
publisher={...},
}
@book{test1,
author={Theodor Fontane},
title={Zaubefloete},
year={1000},
publisher={...},
}
@book{test2,
author={Wolfgang Goethe},
title={Irgendwas},
year={1000},
publisher={...},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MidSep{; }% separator for two elements, not the last two (for citeauthorlist and citetlist)
\newcommand\LastSep{ and }% separator for last two elements
\newcommand\citetlist[1]{%
 \begingroup%
  \let\NAT@open@orig\NAT@open\let\NAT@open\relax\NAT@open@orig
  \let\NAT@close@orig\NAT@close\let\NAT@close\relax%
  \def\NAT@spacechar{, }%
  \let\last@elem\relax
  \let\last@sep\relax
  \@for\@list:=#1\do{%
    \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
      \ifx\last@sep\relax
        \def\last@sep{\LastSep}% the separator between the last two elements should is "and"
      \else\MidSep  % the separator between two elements (not the two last) is a comma
      \fi
      \citet{\last@elem}%
    \fi
    \let\last@elem\@list
  }% the last element of the list:
  \ifx\last@elem\relax\else
    \last@sep\citet{\last@elem}%
  \fi%
 \NAT@close@orig\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\citetlist{test,test1,test2}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost there! :).  Now, I just want to change the `midsep` for a `;`, and I want a comma between the author name and the publication year... is it possible?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Without reinventing the wheel, here's a set of LaTeX3 commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_mariose_cites_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mariose_citecommands_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mariose_citelist:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {% #1 = delimiter, #2 = cite command, #3 = list
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mariose_cites_seq { , } { #3 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_mariose_citecommands_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mariose_cites_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mariose_citecommands_seq { #2 { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_mariose_citecommands_seq {~and~} {#1~} {~and~}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\citetlist}{m}
 {
  \mariose_citelist:nnn { , } { \citet } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\citeplist}{m}
 {
  (\mariose_citelist:nnn { ; } { \citeboth } { #1 })
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\citeboth}{m}{\citeauthor{#1},~\citeyear{#1}}

\begin{document}

\citetlist{Knuth:BAMSN-1-337,Lamport:LDP86,Goosens:LC94}

\citeplist{Knuth:BAMSN-1-337,Lamport:LDP86,Goosens:LC94}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/beebe/texbook1}
\end{document}
```

For `\citeplist` I essentially use `\citeauthor{<key>}~\citeyear{<key>}`.

[image]

A straightforward generalization allows for `\citetlist*` and `\citeplist*` showing the full lists of authors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_mariose_cites_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mariose_citecommands_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mariose_citelist:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {% #1 = delimiter, #2 = cite command, #3 = list
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mariose_cites_seq { , } { #3 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_mariose_citecommands_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mariose_cites_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mariose_citecommands_seq { #2 { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_mariose_citecommands_seq {~and~} {#1~} {~and~}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\citetlist}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\mariose_citelist:nnn { , } { \citet* } { #2 }}
   {\mariose_citelist:nnn { , } { \citet } { #2 }}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\citeplist}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {(\mariose_citelist:nnn { ; } { \citeboth* } { #2 })}
   {(\mariose_citelist:nnn { ; } { \citeboth } { #2 })}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\citeboth}{sm}
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\citeauthor*{#2},~\citeyear{#2}}
   {\citeauthor{#2},~\citeyear{#2}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\citetlist{Knuth:BAMSN-1-337,Lamport:LDP86,Goosens:LC94}

\citeplist{Knuth:BAMSN-1-337,Lamport:LDP86,Goosens:LC94}

\citetlist*{Knuth:BAMSN-1-337,Lamport:LDP86,Goosens:LC94}

\citeplist*{Knuth:BAMSN-1-337,Lamport:LDP86,Goosens:LC94}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/beebe/texbook1}
\end{document}
```

[image]